# Using data from linq query

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, linq

I have a very simple linq query that gets data from two datatables (orderHeader & OrderDetails) and joins them together. What I would like to do is take the order items for each order and pass them to a method for processing.

Here is the query:

```
var results = from orderHeader in dtOrderHeader.AsEnumerable()
join orderDetails in dtOrderDetails.AsEnumerable() on 
  orderHeader.Field<int>("order_ref") equals
  orderDetails.Field<int>("order_id")
select new { 
  orderID = orderHeader.Field<int>("order_ref"), 
  orderItem = orderDetails.Field<string>("product_details") 
};
```

What is the best way to iterate the results for each order?

Thanks

Comment: Anything wrong with `foreach`?

Comment: Are you sure you need `join` there? Perhaps you should `group by` first, and then `join`?

Comment: Sorry, it's not so much how to iterate, it's the how can i split of order details for each order. I was thinking about storing results in a list, then comparing the order number on each iteration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This result set contains multiple orders, this would require a nested foreach

```
foreach (var order in results.Select(r => r.orderID).Distinct()) {
   Console.WriteLine("Order: " + order);
   Console.WriteLine("Items:");
   foreach (var product in results.Where(r => r.orderItem == order)) {
      Console.WriteLine(product.orderItem);
   }
}
```

Comment: Ok, just tested & var order contains an integer value rather than the order object. So I cant output as order.orderID.

Comment: Oops, when you select a single value "Select(r => r.orderID)", you get a list of the type you selected. Corrected my answer :)

Comment: Great! Just needed to add .toString() on the output of the order. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Just one other question...
If I want to be able to pull out more than just the orderID from the orderheader part how can I achieve this?